# Navegação entre modais

Tags: ios, swift, swift-3, uinavigationcontroller

Em minha aplicação IOS tenho uma opção que abre uma modal, nessa modal tenho uma lista de itens, ao clicar em um desses itens eu mostro os detalhes do item selecionado.

A solução adotada hoje foi abrir a modal com os detalhes dentro da modal lista, dando a opção do usuário voltar para a modal com a lista de itens, sem utilizar navigationcontroller, criei um botão onde dou um dismiss na controller. Esses modais são arquivos XIB.

Abaixo minhas chamada:

Abrir minha modal Lista

```
class PrincipalViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func dependente(_ sender: Any) {
        let modalViewController = ListaViewController()

        modalViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
        modalViewController.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve

        present(modalViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Abrir detalhes do item

```
class ListaViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let modalViewController = DetalheViewController()
        modalViewController.modalTransitionStyle = .flipHorizontal
        present(modalViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Acredito que não seja o caminho correto e estou com dificuldades de encontrar/entender a solução certa para fazer essa navegação entre as modais, alguém consegue me auxiliar?

Obrigado,

Comment: O certo seria a sua modal ser uma navigation com a lista como root dessa navigation. Essa questão pode ajudar vc, está em objetive C mas a ideia é a mesma. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479231/modal-view-with-navigation-controller

Comment: A recomendação do @CCastro é a solução ideal para o seu problema. Se uma tela descende da outra, `UINavigationController` é o container view controller que procura para o fluxo da navegação.

Answer (score 0):

Você teria que fazer uma nova navigation para seguir com esse fluxo, exemplo:

```
class PrincipalViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func dependente(_ sender: Any) {
        let modalViewController = ListaViewController()
        modalViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
        modalViewController.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve

        let navigation = UINavigationController(rootViewController: modalViewController)
        present(navigation, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Na outra tela que tem a tableView e precisa da navegação ficaria algo assim:

```
class ListaViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let modalViewController = DetalheViewController()
        modalViewController.modalTransitionStyle = .flipHorizontal
        navigationController?.pushViewController(modalViewController, animated: false)
    }
}
```